SwiftPM Tests Undefined Symbol Working with xcframework
I tried to run my test on target test but when have ran, the compile show the next error
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_BTDxx Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Qxxx Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Qxx
in the package I have a xcframework wrapper that contain a static library .a this is my Package.swift
let package = Package(
    name: "Terminal",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Terminal",
            targets: ["Terminal"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/xxxxxx", exact: "x.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/xxxxxx", exact: "x.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/xxxxxx", exact: "x.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/xxxxxx", exact: "x.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/xxxxxx", exact: "x.0.0"),
        .package(path: "../xx"),
        .package(path: "../xx"),
        .package(path: "../xx"),
        .package(path: "../xx")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "Terminal",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "xxxx", package: "xx"),
                .product(name: "xxx", package: "xxx"),
                .product(name: "xxx", package: "xxx"),
                .product(name: "xxx", package: "xxx"),
                .product(name: "xxx", package: "xxx"),
                "xxx",
                "xxx",
                "xxx",
                "xxx",
                "ReaderTerminal"
            ]),
        .target(
            name: "ReaderTerminal",
            dependencies: ["reader-ios-sdk"],
            path: "Sources/Bridge"),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "reader-ios-sdk",
            path: "Libs/reader-ios-sdk.xcframework"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "TerminalTests",
            dependencies: ["Terminal"]),
    ]
)

I tried to add flags in .testTarget
I added:
linkerSettings: [ .linkedLibrary("c++"), .unsafeFlags(["-fobjc-link-runtime"])]
linkerSettings: [ .linkedLibrary("c++abi"), .unsafeFlags(["-fobjc-link-runtime"])]),
 linkerSettings: [ .linkedLibrary("c++abi"), .unsafeFlags(["-x objective-c"])]),
but always I get the same error
do you added import the xcframework and do the unitest on package?
